# Complicated query involving calculation of date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a list of backup details for multiple companies in a database. Here is how it is setup (roughly):

Fields:

```
ID
Company (nvarchar)
Servername (nvarchar)
Finaljobstatus (nvarchar)
actualstarttime (datetime)
endtime (datetime)
totaldatasizebytes (nvarchar)
tasktypeid (nvarchar)
```

A company could have hundreds of rows in the database. I am wondering if I can do what I need to do directly within the SQL query which in logical terms:

1. Work out the amount of days between the first recorded backup and the last recorded backup (could use actualstarttime)
2. Work out the difference in totaldatasizebytes between those two records
3. Present an average increase per day
4. All the above should only happen when finaljobstatus = 19 or finaljobstatus = 3 and tasktypeid = 100

I realise this is made more difficult because the person who designed this made numeric fields nvarchars, but this query is beyond me so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We would love to field questions like these over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Nick: It's just SQL. It's not really something you'd need a DBA to answer.

Comment: @Catcall - We welcome all SQL questions, especially non-basic ones. Despite our name (which some of us are looking to [change](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/270/2660)), we are for answering any kind of serious database question, not just on database administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the answer to part 1.

```
select
  Company,
  min(actualstarttime),
  max(actualstarttime)
from
  mytable
where
  finaljobstatus = 19 or (finaljobstatus = 3 and tasktypeid = '100')
group by
  Company
```

This could then be extended to give you the other details. This is probably easier by storing the intermediate results in a temp table:

```
select
  Company,
  minID = min(ID),
  maxID = max(ID)
into
  #t
from
  mytable
where
  finaljobstatus = 19 or (finaljobstatus = 3 and tasktypeid = '100')
group by
  Company
```

With this temp table you can answer questions 1 - 3

```
select
  #t.Company,
  answer1 = datediff(d, tMin.actualstarttime, tMax.actualstarttime),
  answer2 = (convert(bigint, tMax.totaldatasizebytes) - convert(bigint, tMin.totaldatasizebytes),
  answer3 = (convert(bigint, tMax.totaldatasizebytes) - convert(bigint, tMin.totaldatasizebytes) / datediff(d, tMin.actualstarttime, tMax.actualstarttime)
from
  #t
  inner join mytable tMin
    on #t.minID = tMin.ID
  inner join mytable tMax
    on #t.maxID = tMax.ID
```

Remember to drop the temp taple when you are finished

```
drop table #t
```

Comment: For "the answer to part 1", `max(endtime)` might be a better choice than `max(actualstarttime)`. It's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Could be. I don't know if OP wants start to start, or start to end. Either way, the prinicple is illustrated I hope. Once the Min and Max records for each company are in a temp table you can extract pretty much any stat you want.

Comment: Your division for the average will always result in a whole number because they are `BIGINT`. So for example if the file size went from 2 bytes to 9 bytes between the two days, yours will return 4 instead of 4.5.

Comment: My apologies. I presumed that when measuring the size of an average company backup, it would be sufficient to measure to the nearest byte. @Wil is indeed correct that these values need to be casted to decimals or floats to measure fractional bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I started to think about it and wondered if there was a way to streamline it and do so without temp tables. Since everything I've been doing lately seems to involved CTEs I worked up a solution going that route. This was the result, it might not be the most efficient way to go about it from a CTE perspective but I prefer it to a bunch of temp tables and it leaves most of the nasty casting out of the final `SELECT`:

```
   ;WITH CompanyDays
AS (
    SELECT
        Company
        ,MIN(ActualStartTime) AS StartDate
        ,MAX(endtime) AS EndDate
    FROM Companies
    WHERE finaljobstatus = '19' OR (finaljobstatus = '3' AND tasktypeid = '100')
    GROUP BY Company
    )
,StartFileSize
AS
(
    SELECT 
            c.Company
            ,c.totaldatasizebytes AS StartFileSize
            ,cd.StartDate
            ,cd.EndDate        
    FROM Companies AS c
    JOIN CompanyDays AS cd ON c.actualstarttime= cd.StartDate
    WHERE (finaljobstatus = '19' OR (finaljobstatus = '3' AND tasktypeid = '100'))
)
,EndFileSize
AS
(
    SELECT 
            c.Company
            ,CAST(s.StartFileSize AS DECIMAL(18,0)) AS StartFileSize
            ,CAST(c.totaldatasizebytes AS DECIMAL(18,0)) AS EndFileSize
            ,DATEDIFF(dd,cd.StartDate,cd.EndDate) AS DayDiff
            ,CAST(c.totaldatasizebytes AS DECIMAL(18,0)) - CAST(s.StartFileSize AS DECIMAL(18,0)) AS FileDiff
            ,cd.StartDate
            ,cd.EndDate        
    FROM Companies AS c
    JOIN CompanyDays AS cd ON c.endtime= cd.EndDate
    JOIN StartFileSize AS s ON c.Company = s.Company
    WHERE (finaljobstatus = '19' OR (finaljobstatus = '3' AND tasktypeid = '100'))
)


SELECT 
    e.Company
    ,DayDiff
    ,FileDiff
    ,(FileDiff/e.StartFileSize)/DayDiff AS AveragePercentageChange
FROM EndFileSize AS e
```

Note that `DATEDIFF` on the actual start and end dates with times might skew things slightly because it only counts the actual day boundaries that are crossed (i.e., Midnight). In most cases, that will be perfectly fine. If not, you can take another measure like datediff in hours and divide the result by 24; minutes and divide it by 1440; seconds and divide it by 86400 depending on exactly how precise you need the day difference to be.

EDIT: I realized my math was off. What if there was a decrease between the two days? Fixed that and moved some more casting into the CTE.